# How do I write a parallel reduction using strategies in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing

In high-performance computing, sums, products, etc are often calculated using a "parallel reduction" that takes *n* elements and completes in O(log *n*) time (given enough parallelism). In Haskell, we usually use a *fold* for this kind of calculation, but evaluation time is always linear in the length of the list.

Data Parallel Haskell has some of this built in, but what about in the common framework of a list? Can we do it with `Control.Parallel.Strategies`?

So, assuming `f` is associative, how do we write

`parFold :: (a -> a -> a) -> [a] -> a`

so that `parFold f xs` only needs time logarithmic in `length xs`?

Comment: As folks have noted, list is a poor data structure for recursive parallel splitting. You want some sort of binary tree/rope structure such as in the Fortress language: http://labs.oracle.com/projects/plrg/Publications/ICFPAugust2009Steele.pdf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think a list is the right data type for this.  Because it's just a linked list, the data will necessarily be accessed sequentially.  Although you can evaluate the items in parallel, you won't gain much in the reduction step.  If you really need a List, I think the best function would be just

```
parFold f = foldl1' f . withStrategy (parList rseq)
```

or maybe

```
parFold f = foldl1' f . withStrategy (parBuffer 5 rseq)
```

If the reduction step is complex, you might get a gain by subdividing the list like this:

```
parReduce f = foldl' f mempty . reducedList . chunkList . withStrategy (parList rseq)
 where
  chunkList list = let (l,ls) = splitAt 1000 list in l : chunkList ls
  reducedList = parMap rseq (foldl' f mempty)
```

I've taken the liberty of assuming your data is a `Monoid` for mempty, if this isn't possible you can either replace mempty with your own empty type, or worse case use `foldl1'`.

There are two operators from `Control.Parallel.Strategies` in use here.  The `parList` evaluates all items of the list in parallel.  After that, the `chunkList` divides the list into chunks of 1000 elements.  Each of those chunks is then reduced in parallel by the `parMap`.

You might also try

```
parReduce2 f = foldl' f mempty . reducedList . chunkList
 where
  chunkList list = let (l,ls) = splitAt 1000 list in l : chunkList ls
  reducedList = parMap rseq (foldl' f mempty)
```

Depending on exactly how the work is distributed, one of these may be more efficient than the others.

If you can use a data structure that has good support for indexing though (Array, Vector, Map, etc.), then you can do binary subdivisions for the reduction step, which will probably be better overall.

Comment: Thanks, John. I like the idea of using foldl' over chunks. But after each chunk is reduced, the outer foldl' is sequential, and its input could be very large. What's the best way to express the recursion? The input may or may not be a list, but this should be expressible using strategies.

Comment: The `parMap` function in `reducedList` will evaluate all of the chunks in parallel.  But if your input is so large that you don't want to load it all in memory at once, then you can use laziness and parBuffer.  I've had very good success with `parBuffer` because it lets you exploit parallelism and laziness.  I think it will work if you use `reducedList = withStrategy (parBuffer 10 rseq) . map (foldl' f mempty)`.  I think this is better than recursion for Lists because you avoid multiple traversals.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a good start:

```
parFold :: (a -> a -> a) -> [a] -> a
parFold f = go
  where
  strategy = parList rseq

  go [x] = x
  go xs = go (reduce xs `using` strategy)

  reduce (x:y:xs) = f x y : reduce xs
  reduce list     = list   -- empty or singleton list
```

It works, but parallelism is not so great. Replacing `parList` with something like `parListChunks 1000` helps a bit, but speedup is still limited to under 1.5x on an 8-core machine.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your `parFold` function is supposed to do. If that is intended to be a parallel version of foldr or foldl, I think its definition is wrong.

```
parFold :: (a -> a -> a) -> [a] -> a

// fold right in haskell (takes 3 arguments)
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

Fold applies the same function to each element of the list and accumulates the result of each application. Coming up with a parallel version of it, i guess, would require that the function application to the elements are done in parallel - a bit like what `parList` does.

```
    par_foldr :: (NFData a, NFData b) => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
    par_foldr f z [] = z
    par_foldr f z (x:xs) = res `using` \ _ -> rseq x' `par` rdeepseq res
                       where x' = par_foldr f z xs
                             res = x `f` x'
```